# How to parse tab-delimited file into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, fgetcsv, csv

I was tasked with parsing a tab-delimited file and inserting the values into the database. Find a selection of the tab-delimited file below.

```
"030-36-2"      0   0   14  "P"
"030-38-2"      0   0   14  "S"
"030-40-2"      0   0   14  "S"
"031-2-2"       1   0       "O"
"031-3-2"       4   0       "O"
"032-36-26"     0   0   14  "S"
"032-38-26"     0   0   14  "S"
"032-40-26"     0   0   14  "S"
"070-140-161"   0   0   14  "S"
"070-140-162"   2   0       "D"
"070-83-161"    0   0   14  "S"
```

I'm using fgetcsv with my delimiter set to a tab (9) but upon executing the code I am only getting a small percentage of total values inserted into the database.
This is my code:

```
if(($handle = fopen("mytabdelimitedfile.txt","r"))!==FALSE){
    fgetcsv($handle, 0,chr(9));
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,chr(9)))!==FALSE){
        print_r($data[0]); 
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) VALUES('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]')"); 
    }
}
```

The first 4 records are not inserted but it starts with "031-3-2", then skips down to "070-140-162". I fear the result may have to do with some values missing but I cannot seem to discern a pattern.

Does anyone have any insight regarding this? Does the issue have to do with some values missing? Is there any workaround? (I don't have any control over source data)

Also another note: when I use Excel => import data from text => tab-delimited, the results are perfect. But of course I cannot use Excel as the data is updated on an hourly basis. Please, any point in the right direction would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) if you can.

Comment: replace tab with a comma or semicolon and then parse it more easily?

Comment: I replace tabs with the word TAAAB or SPAAACE. Which can then be exploded or preg_split conveniently

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like VMai saide, use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'mytabdelimitedfile.txt'
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS
  TERMINATED BY '\t'
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
```

Also, I really hope those aren't your actual column names.

And don't rely on Excel as an example for anything. It hasn't handled CSV in a sane manner since at least 2007.